# CSS - IE7 & 8 Issues

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

**UPDATE**

I noticed this occurs only when I use slideUp/Down.If I use show/hide everythings OK

**END UPDATE**

In my site I am developing/designing, I have 2 issues.

In IE7, the sliding menu seems to not show, until I move the mouse abit.

[alt text http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/4422/7282009105215pm.png](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/4422/7282009105215pm.png)

In IE8, after a menu slides up, the margin seems to be removed.

[alt text http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/4592/7282009105247pm.png](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/4592/7282009105247pm.png)

The JS (if required)

```
$(function() {
    $("#mainNav li:has(ul) > a").addClass("hasMore");
    $("#mainNav li").hoverIntent(menuOn, menuOff);
    $.each($("#mainNav a.active").parents("li"), function() {
        $(this).children("a:first").addClass("active");
    });
    $("#mainNav").mouseleave(function() {
        $("ul", this).slideUp(200);
        $(".open", this).removeClass("open");
    });
});
function menuOn() {
    var childUl = $(this).children("ul");
    if (childUl.length) {
        childUl.slideDown(200);
        $(this).addClass("open");

        $("ul", $(this).closest("li").siblings("li")).slideUp(200);
        $(this).closest("li").siblings("li").removeClass("open");
    }
}
function menuOff() {

}
```

The CSS

```
#mainNav, #mainNav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#mainNav ul {
    display: none;
}
#mainNav li {
    position: relative;
}
#mainNav li ul {
    margin: 2px 0 2px 5px;
    background-color: #282a33;
}
#mainNav a:link, #mainNav a:visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    color: #282a33;
    background-color: #ffe7a6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mainNav a:hover, #mainNav a:active {
    background-color: #e6c468;
}
#mainNav > li.open > a.hasMore {
    background-color: #e6c468;
}
#mainNav > li > a.active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #fa8000 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#mainNav li li a:link, #mainNav li li a:active, #mainNav li li a:visited, #mainNav li li a:hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    font-family: Georgia, Garamond, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
#mainNav li li a:hover, #mainNav li li a:active {
    color: #ffe7a6;
}
#mainNav li li a.active {
    color: #fa8000;
}
#mainNav a.hasMore {
    background-image: url(../images/section_collapsed.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
#mainNav a.active.hasMore,
#mainNav a.hasMore:hover,
#mainNav li li > a.hasMore {
    background-image: url(../images/section_collapsed2.png);
}
#mainNav li.open > a.active.hasMore,
#mainNav li.open > a.hasMore {
    background-image: url(../images/section_expanded2.png);
}
```

Comment: did you mean for **alt text** to not be a link? it's escaped in your source.

Comment: i dont really get what u mean? alt text? did i escape anything?

Comment: i noticed that if i use show() & hide() instead of slides non of these occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it...

```
#mainNav {
  zoom:1;
}
```

Read more about the [concept of hasLayout in IE](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html)

Comment: does not seem to... zoom causes the ul to stretch somehow over the main content. i tried height:1px also. it still does not work. isit something abt peek a boo? its supposed to be fixed in IE7?

http://iceangel89.110mb.com/templates/em/1_index.html