# How do you debug Display/CSS issues in multiple browsers?

Tags: css, firebug, browser-testing

Say I need to develop a web site for multiple browsers. major ones - Firefox, Safari, IE, Opera, Chrome

How do you debug display issues? In Firefox there's Firebug, which is great. There also is a Firebug Lite for other browsers, but it's not full featured - it does not refresh in real-time. For example, if I suspect that jQuery is slowing it down (adding classes, etc), how would I find out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Firefox has [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/)
- Opera has [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)
- IE8 has [developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(VS.85).aspx)
- Webkit browsers (Chrome/Safari) have [web inspector](http://webkit.org/blog/41/introducing-the-web-inspector/)

Aside from these, you may want to look up the [outline property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#dynamic-outlines) which adds a border to elements, but without disrupting the page flow. This is useful for side-by-side comparisons.

If you have some classes being applied with jQuery, simply use the outline property on them and it should appear when the class is added.

```
.class1 {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
.class2 {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: hmm IE6/7 does not have anything good tho? btw, i think IE* developer's tools dont have realtime updates like firebug for FF has? cos now the problem i am facing is when during/after jquery animaions. so i need the css to update there so i know whats happening. my qn for that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194812/css-ie7-8-issues

Answer (score 0):

IE8 includes great [developper tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd565628%28en-us,VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can validate CSS using [W3C CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

About [About the CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/about.html)

Developer Tools

- [IE Developers Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd565628(en-us,VS.85).aspx)
- [Opera Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)
- [Safari Web Inspector](http://webkit.org/blog/41/introducing-the-web-inspector/)

Answer (score 0):

For cross-browser debugging, you can use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html). It's like Firebug itself, but as an external JavaScript library and tested in FF, Opera Safari and even the good ol' IE (as the webpage states).

Comment: firebug lite does not refresh realtime, eg. when i change classes with jquery or do animation.

Comment: Really? I thought it does, but it's a time ago now, since I used it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my new tool to view the layout of any element on your page by mousing over it - CROSS BROWSER!

[HTML Box Visualizer - GitHub](https://github.com/ghmcadams/boxvis)